# Flashing Monitor with 2 monitors plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, flashing

I'm having trouble with one of my monitors turning on and off for a few seconds and lines flashing on the screen. This only happens on my main monitor. When I unplug my second monitor, the main monitor acts normally.

I have a Radeon HD 6850 and am running Windows 7 64bit

I've installed the latest drivers for the graphics card.

This only had just started happening when I replaced my Motherboard/Processor/RAM and had to change from 32bit to 64bit because of the amount of RAM. Also, I had been having BSoD but have fixed that because I had a faulty RAM stick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been the power supply not having enough power for the graphics card